# Creating fake publication to use "Also Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications"

Tags: publishing, sdl-tridion, content-manager, blueprint

We are using SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 and currently we have custom tool(Internal) for  Publishing /Unpublishing items in multiple publications at once.

Recently one of the publisher asked us to look into below option.

[image]

Is it okay to create a **Fake publication**, so that users can simply use that publication to publish and unpublish to all child publications.

what are the disadvantages of this implementation?

Comment: The ability to selectively choose child Publications to publish from was a [popular idea on Tridion Sites Ideas](https://community.rws.com/ideas/tridion-ideas/i/tridion-sites-ideas/publish-to-selection-of-child-publications) and was delivered as part of Tridion Sites 9.5 in the Experience Space UI. See [my post on other Experience Space features](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/what-does-a-new-ui-mean-for-sdl-tridion-sites-9-5) which also shows the ability to publish to select child publications while _skipping_ the parent publication.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this done in a few implementations. The main things that spring to mind to watch for are:

1. Licensing implications, if you're paying per Publication then there may be a threshold that one extra takes you over (then it's ALL YOUR FAULT ;) )
2. Naming. Don't give it some funky technical name, discuss it with the editors that will be using the system and ensure it makes sense to them
3. Over-publishing. Editors are busy people. They don't like doing things twice (probably the reason you've asked this question!) but that may also mean they're happy to do something once ... even if there's (technical) waste. Be sure the design means only what needs to be getting published is - and if not - then the editor is **aware of the implications** and **takes responsibility** for that.
4. Do you have workflow? Check if publishing things to the 'other' targets in the workflow state they will be in is going to work as expected.

Of course, I'm assuming you're looking at only a publication or two so it won't have much impact in terms of topology complexity... but something you will want to consider too.

Answer (score 2):

There is one additional tech debt to this:

- if you allow publishing from this publication then you have all these records in the broker database, which brings up the size of the broker.
  You can mitigate this with a custom resolver where you remove items during the resolving phase so that these transactions are empty, so you are complicating architecture to fix the size of the broker.

As you see, it gets complicated really easily.

What I would suggest to you is analyze your blueprint. See if you can already reuse some publications for this. In general, the sample blueprint structure provided on docs.rws.com is really great example how it should be setup. So don't reinvent the wheel. Just use it.

Comment: I shared how to set up this [fake publication approach for the older-style publishing](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/no-faking-publish-from-a-parent-publication-without-faking-a-publication-target). This won't apply anymore with Topology Manager, but see comment from @BartKoopman on using a custom resolver to actually _remove_ the parent publishing transactions from the request.